# clickable text inside a cell in nattable

Tags: java, nattable

We have just started implementing NatTable and we are very pleased by the performance increase we are seeing. However, we are having trouble implementing a specific functionality.

What we would like is to have clickable text inside a cell, which would then reference a row in the table which we select and bring into view. Basically, something like:

```
Row # | Name # | Related links
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Row 1 | Name 1 | Name 2 Name 3
Row 2 | Name 2 | Name 1
Row 3 | Name 3 | Name 1
```

By clicking on the text `"Name 3"` in the cell on `Row 1, Row 3` would be selected.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a trivial task. You will need to register a `IMouseAction` similar what we show in the latest version of `Rendering_cells_as_a_link_and_button` in the repository (part of the 1.6 development).

But there the whole cell is used as a link. You request a link inside a cell text, and maybe even multiple different links inside one cell. That would mean your implementation would need to inspect the text inside the cell at the click position, and determine the action based on that. As of now NatTable does not provide a solution for that and I have no solution for that either. Probably some calculation with dynamic in-memory rendering to know that is rendered on the GC at the given click position.